# How to define vue template in pug?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

How to have Vue.js recognize Pug in a String template? Example:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `
    div
      div`})
```

I saw how this can be done in standalone templates, as in:

```
<template lang='pug'>
  div
    div
</template>
```

But I would like to be able to use pug in String templates.

Comment: It is easy to find how to use Pug in standalone templates, but no info on how to use it in a String template.

Comment: I think it is just not an option. Those String templates are compiled on the client, which would require doing Pug translation step there too.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d) introduces the different ways you can define a component in Vue.js, but I struggled to understand the true differences between them even after reading it a few times.  When you use pug, the x-template is by far the superior method.

Answer (score 12):

We use pug in our vue templates using x-template, here's a shell component:

```
script(type="text/x-template" id="admin-tags")
  div
    h1 Admin Tags
script.
  var AdminTags = Vue.component('admin-tags', {
    template: "#admin-tags",
    props: ["options"],
    data: function(){
      return {
      }
    }
  });
```

Then we just include the files with the components in the parent template.  It works really well.

UPDATE 04/2019: I have recently started a new project using vue-cli and [vue-cli-plugin-pug](https://github.com/jaeming/vue-cli-plugin-pug) has been working very well.  It's as easy as this:

```
<template lang='pug'>
  div
    h1 Home
    ul
      li A
      li B
      li C
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: not sure why this wasnt upvoted, this is the correct answer

Comment: I've rather given up on expecting rational votes any more here, but I am just happy to help others.  I do appreciate you saying that, though.

Comment: tried your solution, works like a charm so upvote, isnt that how SO is supposed to work :)

Comment: Well, you are doing the right thing.  This can be a silly place though.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon @Graham's answer, you can also use just:

```
//- In the Pug file
script#my-component-template(type="text/x-template")
  div
    div
```

and then

```
// In the Javascript file
Vue.component('MyComponent', {
    template: '#my-component-template',
});
```

If you are making a Codepen.io pen for example, I think this way is cleaner. Pug goes to the "HTML" box (outside of the element you mount Vue to) and Javascript goes to "JS" box.